# How to do a unwildcarded search in MarkLogic using jsearch.value?

Tags: javascript, json, search, marklogic, marklogic-9

I need to look into multiple JSON documents in MarkLogic and need to use jsearch.values specifically. However, all the results are wildcarded by default. Is there any option that I can use to specify that I want my search to be unwildcarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`where()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/ValuesSearch.where) clause with a [`cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery) query restricts lookups to documents with an exact match. An example:

```
jsearch.values(['propName'])
       .where(cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery('propName', '=', 'Stack string'))
       .result();
```

As noted in the earlier version of this answer that misinterpreted the question, the [`match()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/ValuesSearch.match) operation applies a wildcard match while looking up values.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: On a match, I can say match(stack*) which then gives me a wildcarded result on "stack string". How do I match for the string that contains a "*" in it like "Stack* string" ?

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding. Revised the answer.